# WPF Image control is not automatic update from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am new to WPF and C#, I try to implement an Image control, which is updated whenever there is new data coming from serial port, but failed after a lot of attempts. It just shows the black image at the beginning and when there is new data coming, the Image control is not updated **(ImageSource in ImageViewModel was not updated and event NotifyPropertyChanged was not fired)**. Can anyone help me out?

I have 3 classes and 1 Usercontrol. They are ImageViewModel, ImageConverter, Control and UserControl and UserControl code behind.

My ImageViewModel class

```
public class ImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private System.Drawing.Image _img;

    public System.Drawing.Image ImageSource
    {
        get { return _img; }
        set { _img = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSource"); }
    }

    public ImageViewModel()
    {
        ImageSource = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(320, 240);
    }
}
```

My ImageConverter Class

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Drawing.Image), typeof(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource))]
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // empty images are empty...
        if (value == null) { return null; }
        else
        {
            var image = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
            // Winforms Image we want to get the WPF Image from...
            var bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            // Save to a memory stream...
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            // Rewind the stream...
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Control class

```
    public void OpenPort()
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort.Open();
            SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(receivedDataFromSerialPort);
            SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            SerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void ClosePort()
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort.Close();
            SerialPort.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(receivedDataFromSerialPort);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    ImageViewModel ivm = new ImageViewModel();
    private void receivedDataFromSerialPort(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image tmp = new Bitmap(320,240);

        //other codes
        ivm.ImageSource = tmp;

    }
```

My Usercontrol

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <imgcv:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:ImageViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel Height="240" Width="300">
    <Image Width="320" Height="240" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource,IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter},ConverterParameter=ImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
</StackPanel>
```

UserControl code behind

```
public partial class UserControls : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    Control ctrl = new Control();

    //other codes
    ctrl.OpenPort();
    //other codes
    ctrl.ClosePort();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see the event, but i miss the interface on your class? Is that a typo or haven't you used the interface? If the later, than that is your problem.

Comment: There should be only one `ImageViewModel` class instantiated. Why have u defined an instance in XAML? <UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:ImageViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: thanks for advice, but i've added INotifyPropertyChanged in my ImageViewModel class but nothing changes.

Comment: is `receivedDataFromSerialPort` method written in the code behind of your `UserControl`?

Comment: receivedDataFromSerialPort method is written in Control class, not code behind of the UserControl.

Comment: How are Control and UserControl related? Is one part of the other? You have to make sure that both act on the same `ImageViewModel` instance.

Comment: In UserControl code behind, i created new Control(), which supports open, close serial port.

Comment: Is there any reason why it is a Control? It could be an ordinary class. And you would perhaps just pass the `ImageViewModel` instance as a constructor parameter to that class, so that it can be used in the `receivedDataFromSerialPort` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a converter? Your User control can be created this way:

```
<UserControl Name="userControl1">
  <StackPanel Height="240" Width="300">
     <Image Width="320" Height="240" Source="{Binding Source}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Your ViewModel class can be as follows:

```
 public class ImageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ImageSource _source;
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return _source; }
            set
            {
                _source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }

        public ImageViewModel()
        {
            //Initialize Source using new bitmap or any other way
        }
    }
```

ViewModelBase will implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the OnPropertyChanged method should be present in ViewModelBase.

This should work. I just came across in your question that your image will be loaded asynchronously. In that case you can update the "Source" using the Dispatcher.

The data context can be assigned in the following way:

```
ImageViewModel imageViewModel= new ImageViewModel();
userControl1.DataContext     = imageViewModel;
```

There is one more method to assign data context which I use most of the time:

1)Bind a Window control(MainWindow)which encloses the user control to a MainWindowViewModel

2)MainWindowViewModel will have a Visibility parameter to control the User Controls Visibility.

3)`<usercontrol DataContext="{Binding imageViewModel}" Visibility="{Binding imageViewVisibility}"/>`

The data context parameter will be present in MainWindowViewModel.

4) MainWindowViewModel:ViewModelbase

{

```
  ImageViewModel _viewModel;
  public ImageViewModel imageViewModel
  {
      get{ return _viewModel; }
      set
      {
          _viewModel=value;
          OnPropertyChanged("imageViewModel");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the serial port handling class does not need to be derived from Control. It could be an ordinary class, which gets the view model instance passed to its constructor:

```
public class SerialPortController
{
    private ImageViewModel ivm;

    public SerialPortController(ImageViewModel ivm)
    {
        this.ivm = ivm;
    }

    public void OpenPort()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void ClosePort()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void receivedDataFromSerialPort(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your UserControl would now use the `SerialPortController` like this:

```
public partial class UserControls : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    private SerialPortController ctrl;

    public UserControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // pass ImageViewModel from the UserControl's DataContext
        ctrl = new SerialPortController(DataContext as ImageViewModel);
    }

    //other code
    ctrl.OpenPort();
    //other code
    ctrl.ClosePort();
}
```